# Replace matching date codes in a string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I'm wondering whether the following can be somehow refactored into a more generic way of replacing date codes in a string.
I simply want to replace ex. "filenameMMddyyyy" with "filename04132018". 
I want it also to work with formats such as "filename_yyyy", "filenameddMM", "filename_DDmmYYYY"

```
filename = Regex.Replace(filename, "dd", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
filename = Regex.Replace(filename, "MM", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
filename = Regex.Replace(filename, "yyyy", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could simply escape any non-formatted part of the input string and use the `DateTime.ToString` method directly.

Comment: Why do you people down-vote my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplyfy your code like this:

```
var formattedString = $"filename{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy")}";
```

There is no need for a Regex here. I don't think you can do it more generic. I would just simplify it like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filename1 = ReplaceFileName("filenameMMddyyyy");
    var filename2 = ReplaceFileName("filename_yyyy");
    var filename3 = ReplaceFileName("filenameddMM");
}

private static string ReplaceFileName(string filename)
{
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    filename = filename.Replace("dd", dateTime.ToString("dd"));
    filename = filename.Replace("MM", dateTime.ToString("MM"));
    filename = filename.Replace("yyyy", dateTime.ToString("yyyy"));
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: I suspect `"MMddyyyy"` was only one example and they want it to work with any input format that contains `MM`, `dd` and/or `yyyy`

Comment: It is always the same: When the question is not clear, we are always guessing an answer...

Comment: Sorry I added some extra examples. Yes I want it to work with different formats.

Comment: @Grentley updated my answer. No need for Regex. You cannot be more generic for your concrete problem.

Comment: @Daniel well actually, this will not work if you enter year as "YYYY". I want to ignore the case and use dd or MM or yyyy

Comment: @Grentley well. Now you are getting more precise. In this scenario Regex is fine. But keep in Mind "mm" means "The minute, from 00 through 59." and "MM" means "The month, from 01 through 12." see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings